# zabbix api - filter event

Tags: powershell, zabbix-api

I would like to know if the possible to filter by name (contains) or by tags?

```
$params = @{
    output="extend";
    selectTags="extend";
    groupid = "$groupID"
    filter=@{
        .....
    }
}
Invoke-ZabbixAPI -method event.get -params $params
```

How to use filter with name or tags?

Other question:

since we have a lot of servers, most of the time, I get time out error.
«Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"»
Since I cannot change the time out, what's the best way to filter?

Comment: What's the context? Is this a function? Script? You can suppress errors completely with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`, or you can wrap the call to `Invoke-ZabbixAPI` in a `try{}catch{}` block, or redirect the error stream from the containing block... what's best depends on the context.

Comment: It's a script. I don't want to "hide" the error.
I just want to optimize the search, so don't get a timeout error.

Comment: You're gonna have to show us the filter parameters if you need help optimizing them